# Permutations and combinations and divisibility problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have a problem with this question. I solved it and also got the correct answer but my process is not correct as the solution given in the book is completely different.

> The number of $5$ digit numbers which are divisible by $4$, with digits from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and the repetition of digits allowed, is ___ .

What I did was that I took the unit digit only 4 but as I checked the solution  their are also some numbers ending with 2 and divisible by 4 . But using only 4 as the unit digit I got the correct answer.

Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 2):

The last two digits need to be divisible by 4. This means that given the conditions, the last two digits can be $\{12, 24, 32, 44, 52\}$

Since the repetition of digits is allowed, the remaining 3 places can be filled in $5^3$ ways for each of the 5 cases. The total number of ways is thus $5 \times 5^3 = 625$

Comment: I used 4 as the unit digit and then rest of the 4 places can be filled in 5×5×5×5 ways i.e. 625

Comment: What's wrong with this??

Comment: @Aakankshasharma What is the divisibility test for 4?

Comment: The last two digits should be divisible by 4

Comment: Exactly: in these 5 cases I mentioned, the last two digits form a number that is divisible by 4. That's why this approach is correct. If the unit digit is 4, then 11114 is a number that you can make which is not divisible by 4.